# Reproducing Instagram request with Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, mechanize

I'm trying to reproduce the AJAX query Instagram does when you visit https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/madrid/ for learning purposes.

The request the browser does when visiting the URL above is `https://www.instagram.com/query/`. [These](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/63404b7cf653af4002f5039d4a752624) are the parameters I can see in the Network tab in Chrome.

I'm trying to reproduce that query by two means:
- Using just `Net::HTTP` 
- Using Mechanize to let it handle cookies and other stuff

None of them is working for me.

[**Using Net::HTTP**](https://gist.github.com/bgvo/06ca663d16c6e311ab89572ffd46f015)

[**Using Mechanize**](https://gist.github.com/bgvo/62f319b33fd5e1eb678c0adcde7409a9)

Both methods give me a 403 Forbidden Error.

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to use the `x-csrftoken` value from the cookies.

Comment: Yeah, you can't use your browser's session data in mechanize, because it's using a different session.